# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_split()

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to install the Pagebuilder plugin for WordPress running on PHP5.4.33 I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_split() in /home/***/public_html/mytheme/wp-content/plugins/page-builder/class/PB.PageBuilder.class.php on line 955

The full function in B.PageBuilder.class.php is as follows (see line 955 below)

```
function formatName($oName)
{
    $nName=null;
    $data=mb_split('_',$oName);  /*** This is line 955 ***/

    foreach($data as $value) $nName.=ucfirst($value);

    return($nName);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you enabled mbstring in your php.ini file? http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me on fresh AWS install of Ubuntu 18.04.1, PHP 7.2.10

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

Comment: This worked well for me, with the exception that I installed the version corresponding to my current php one found in `php --version`.

Comment: As @InsideClaw mentioned it's better to install the newest possible i.e. `apt install php-mbstring` or just use `aptitude` for easier searching for current packages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to  enabled `mbstring` in your `php.ini` file

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php